# How to Create a Select Filter for Parent and Child Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this Wordpress category structure:

- State 1

  - City Name
  - City Name
  - City Name
- State 2

  - City Name
  - City Name
  - City Name

What I need are two selects that works like this: In the first one, only parent categories will appear, in this case the states only, e. g. *State 1* and *State 2*.

When one state is selected the next/second select should list the children of the selected parent, in my above example the city names.

Example: When I select *New York* (state) the second select will show all New York cities. Then, I will press Search and it should go to http://mywebsite.com/state-selected/city/selected.

Comment: from where this state/country list will come? Is it will be hard-coded or You will fetch from db?

Comment: Try using the term 'chained select' in your searching.  Maybe look at a plugin like this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: @Ashwani the state/city is coming from wordpress database.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me now:

I used the plugin: [http://appelsiini.net/projects/chained.](http://appelsiini.net/projects/chained) You can see the example, it's perfect.

Then I used get_categories( $args ) twice, each one inside one select element.

The first one, only searching per parents and then putting them into options inside the loop.

The second only filtering by children and then putting all them inside options as well.

So, just used the Chained JQuery Plugin!